# Dropdown for weight

Tags: stock, dropdown-attribute

I'd like to sell meat in my magento store. 
Therefore I want a dropdown for weight from 500g to 12000g in 500g steps. I tried to implement this by using "custom options". The problem is, that the stock only decreases by 1 per order (works as designed ^^).

Comment: Did you check out this link ?
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4256/selling-products-by-weight-multiple-options-accurate-stock-management?rq=1

Comment: What is the weight of your simple product?

Comment: @eetzen: yes, I checked it out, thx. Using Configurable Products is not worth the effort. Imagine I have a complete cow, so I cut the meat from the cow, and do not have 10 packages of 500g, 5 packages of 1000g a.s.o. I have one piece but I want to sell portions of 500g. Hard to explain for me, sry.

Answer (score 3):

You should use Configurable product with weight attribute variation.

1. Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes -> Add New Attribute "Meat Weight"
2. The attribute should be drop-down, Use To Create Configurable Product & Global.
3. Create all options under this attribute like 500g, 1000g, ..., 12000g
4. Now Create a Configurable product with attribute "Meat Weight", enter the description and in Associated products, create simple products under this configurable product.

Please let me know, if you face any problem implementing the solution.